# SQL Agent vs AutoSys

Tags: sql-server, autosys, sql-agent

We are using SQL Server 2014, and have around 250 SQL Agent jobs.  The vast majority are running SSIS packages, and SQL Agent runs on a separate server from the data.

I've been asked to determine if we would gain anything by moving the scheduling aspect of SQL Agent to AutoSys.  We would still use SQL Agent as a container for jobs, just AutoSys for the scheduling.

Out AutoSys environment is 11.3.6.SP7.1589.  Also, our AutoSys environment does not use the advanced job types that are now available with Autosys 11.3.  Only Box and Command jobs are available to us.

Does anyone have experience with AutoSys, or have an opinion of why one would be better than the other?

Comment: I don't see how a scheduling a job elsewhere, i.e. a task scheduler, cron job, or autosys would help you gain anything unless your organization uses autosys for other tasks and you want to  consolidate it. So, if you think it'll be easier to manager the scheduling, then maybe... but otherwise I find this far too broad. Perhaps elaboration on what they ware hoping to gain by making the process more complex, unless they view this change as simplifying it.

Comment: Usually a company would choose to make this a change like the one you're describing because there is a problem and the change will solve it.  You sound like you have a solution and you're looking for a problem to solve.  How will you get an ROI if you aren't even sure what you're solving?

Comment: I was trying not to burden the question with two much information.  The reason I was originally asked to look at AutoSys is that we had two ETL systems.  Instead of having to look at two different systems to schedule and view success/failure, we wanted one (AutoSys).  We will be moving, very soon, to just one ETL solution, SSIS.

Also, we liked the idea of Box jobs in AutoSys, being able to thread jobs to run 1 after the other.

Comment: If all you want to do is run ETLs and "soon" all your ETLs will be SSIS runs, stick with Agent.  Simpler, cheaper.  One big gotcha with Autosys is no support for ad-hoc runs with different parameters.  Say you have a job with a date parameter.  Autosys runs the job today and it works.  Then someone asks to run it again for yesterday.  Doing that with and agent job is simple.  Autosys, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @scsimon and @user1443098.  I'm going to recommend that we stick with SQL Agent.